# Wrong number format

Tags: java, android, validation

I'm having the following issue:

here`s my code on the verifying activity:

```
 public void sendVerificationCode(String mobile){
      CodeBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
              "+55"+mobile,
              60,
              TimeUnit.SECONDS,
              TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
              mCallBack
```

and here is my code in the mainActivity:

```
String mPhone = "+"+55+number;
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("mobile", mPhone);
startActivity(intent);
Log.d("clima","hey "+ "+"+55+number);
```

[image]

Comment: can you provide the result of `Log.d("clima","hey "+ "+"+55+number);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the number format is the issue, I think the best thing for you to do would be to add a Log.d call to the sendVerificationCode method. So it would look like this:

```
public void sendVerificationCode(String mobile){
  Log.d("NumberCheck", "The string mobile is - " + mobile); //This should help you identify what the issue is
  CodeBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
          "+55"+mobile,
          60,
          TimeUnit.SECONDS,
          TaskExecutors.MAIN_THREAD,
          mCallBack
```

Then you should be able to see what's causing the issue.

Comment: hey N1234, I`ve tried many different ways, and when I type only mobile (whitout quotes) on the sendVerificationCode my app crashes, I saw the logcat and it says that the given String is empty or null, and I added a Log on the MainActivity,(Log.d("clima","number:  "+ "+"+55+number);) the value of the number that returns after writing my number on the app is the right one, so it should be working. Do you want to see the full code?

Comment: Where is the Log.d call made in the code? Also what is the result of the Log.d call that GianhTran has asked for?

I think the code would definitely help us understand what's going on.

Comment: Edited my answer to offer further help